# Unable to compile a python script using buildozer

Tags: windows, python-2.7, kivy

I am using win 32 python 2.7 and kivy 1.8.0 but on compiling using buildozer for creating an Android app it is showing the following error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>buildozer android debug deploy
I check configuration tokens
Unknown command/target android
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although buildozer works on Windows, python-for-android does not. You need to use OSX or Linux to make an APK with Kivy. Kivy provides a [Linux virtual machine](http://kivy.org/#download) for your convenience.

Comment: sorry for commenting after 5years there is nothing. is there any other way to create apk on windows machine